# Is it possible to deploy a already trained Keras to Sagemaker?

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-ec2, keras, amazon-sagemaker

I was playing with the AWS instances and trying to deploy some locally trained Keras models, but I find no documentation on that. Has anyone already been able to do it?

I tried to use a similar approach to https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/machine-learning/bring-your-own-pre-trained-mxnet-or-tensorflow-models-into-amazon-sagemaker/, but I had no success. I also found some examples for training keras models in the cloud, but I was not able to get the entry_point + artifacts right.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and yes, the official documentation is not much of help.
However, I wrote an [article on that](https://gnomezgrave.com/2018/07/05/using-a-custom-model-for-ml-inference-with-amazon-sagemaker), and I hope it will help you.

Let me know if you need more details. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks I will definitely take a look. A Docker image seems indeed to be the solution.

Answer (score 2):

AWS recently released a [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-trained-keras-or-tensorflow-models-using-amazon-sagemaker/) on this exact same topic which I find very easy and quicker than the docker image route. Hope this helps.